# How to redirect same path for two different domains (multilingual website) to two different files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress multilingual website with different domains to switch between the languages, and I'd like to redirect the user to a file on a path. It is OK if the file is the same for both languages :

```
Redirect 301 /path http://www.domain.com/docs/file.pdf
```

But what if I was to use the same path (i.e. `www.domain.com/path` and `www.domain.fr/path`) to two different files (i.e. `http://www.domain.com/docs/file-en.pdf` and `http://www.domain.fr/docs/file_fr.pdf`)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^path$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/docs/file-en.pdf [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.fr$
RewriteRule ^path$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/docs/file_fr.pdf [L,R=301]
```